# Como centralizar todas as células em uma tabela no LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Criei uma tabela e gostaria de centralizar todas as células. Eu usei o `\centering` mas não está centralizando os dois títulos, o que devo fazer para corrigir isso?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{RF01. Cadastrar cliente} & \textbf{RNF01.01} \\
        \hline
        O sistema deve permitir que o funcionário realize o cadastros de 
        novos clientes. & Só é permitido funcionários realizarem essa função. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tabela de cadastro de clientes}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Possui uma imagem do resultado da tabela? Ou um link de um teste no OverLeaf?

Answer (score 1):

Isto pode ser feito ao iniciar o ambiente `tabular`, da seguinte forma:
`\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}`

O `c` indica que as células daquela coluna devem ser `c`entralizadas.